# Firebase functions causes error when trying to deploy

Tags: typescript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Firebase functions. I have installed it on my pc and now I'm trying to run it but I keep getting this error:

```
=== Deploying to 'app'...
i  deploying firestore, functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/username/Documents/appdevelopment/app/functions
> eslint --ext .js,.ts .

/Users/username/Documents/appdevelopment/app/functions/index.js
0:0  error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript- 
eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: index.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided

/Users/username/Documents/appdevelopment/app/functions/src/index.ts
1:13  warning  'functions' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused- 
vars

✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint --ext .js,.ts .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging 
output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2021-08-15T21_08_19_284Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

That error starts with saying that a file must be included and later that functions is defined but never used. Did I not install something correctly?

This are the commands that I used to install Firebase functions:

- npm install
- npm install -g firebase-tools
- firebase login
- firebase init firestore
- firebase init functions
  I did this all in this folder: Documents/appdevelopment/app/

This is my testfunctions:

```
   const functions = require("firebase-functions");
   const admin     = require('firebase-admin');
   const db        = admin.firestore();

   admin.initializeApp();

   exports.vote = functions.firestore
   .document('Votes/{vote}')
   .onCreate((document, context) => {
    const row       = document.data()['id'];
    const vote      = document.data()['vote'];

    if (vote == 1) {
        const field = '1star';
    } else if (vote == 2) {
        const field = '2star';
    } else if (vote == 3) {
        const field = '3star';
    } else if (vote == 4) {
        const field = '4star';
    } else {
        const field = '5star';
    }

    const incremento = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
    const incrementv = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

    db.doc('message/'+row).set({field: incremento, 'votes': incrementv})


});
```

And then I run firebase deploy and I get the error given above.

----- edit----

After adding an index.js and an index.ts file (I'm not sure which language I set to default.) to functions/src/ the error changed to:

```
deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint 
 /Users/username/Documents/appdevelopment/app/functions
> eslint --ext .js,.ts .

/Users/username/Documents/appdevelopment/
app/functions/src/index.js
0:0  error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set 
for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: src/index.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint --ext .js,.ts .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely   
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2021-08- 
16T08_27_58_329Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non- 
zero exit code1
```

Comment: If you want to know if you did something incorrectly, you should provide clear and complete steps that you took to get to this point.  There should be enough information so that anyone can reproduce the issue by following those same steps.

Comment: I added some informatie about the steps I took.

Comment: If you are using typescript, I think your (`index.ts`) main source file for your Cloud Functions code should be place in `Documents/appdevelopment/app/functions/src/` and there's no index.js in `Documents/appdevelopment/app/functions/`. It seems conflict due to the tool that you are using. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I have put a index.ts and an index.js (because I'm not sure if I set typescript or javascript as the default.)

Comment: I believe you've set the typescript base on your details from the questions. Move/Convert your  `index.js`  codes to `index.ts` and delete the index.js`.

Comment: I'll provide another answer based on our comments.

Answer (score 1):

By **[default](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript#migrating_an_existing_javascript_project_to_typescript)**, if you are using **typescript** tools in Cloud Function for Firebase, your Cloud Functions code should be stored in `index.ts` place in `myproject/functions/src` directory. And according to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript#functions_logs_for_typescript_projects) your `index.ts` is important because during firebase deployment, your project's `index.ts` is transpiled to `index.js`.

But if you have an existing Cloud Functions project that you initialized and developed in JavaScript, you can migrate it to TypeScript using the complete steps in this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript#migrating_an_existing_javascript_project_to_typescript). **Note:** You're strongly encouraged to create a git checkpoint or other backup before starting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed. I had to move index.ts from functions/ -> functions/src/
Now I can deploy my functions.

Comment: index.ts is already in functions/src/ folder but still, I get this error, and moreover, this is compiler generated, it is not advised to make any such changes